# Save negative numbers in Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a negative number in parse `user.set("points",-5)` but the result inside the table is `null`. Positive numbers do not have problems. How I can save negative numbers in Parse?

Thanks

Comment: I save negative numbers in columns of type `Number` in my project using the same technique. You can prove it to yourself by quickly making a new project and saving a negative number to it. Verify your column type is `Number`. Verify that your negative sign is a dash and not mdash. Make sure no cloudcode `beforeSave` hooks are overwriting it.

Comment: what type is the `points` attribute (tested on `Number` type and worked fine), also do you have any cloudCode that might interfere here?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, an afterSave cloud function overwrites the number